# iCloud takes very long to connect to local store and iCloud Changes to the context done affect my fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, icloud, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When my app loads it give that notification that its using local store: 1 usually it takes 4 to 5 minutes before it returns using local store :0. Not only that reloading using NSNotifications does not seem to work although going to a new view then back does.

appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTime"]){
        UIAlertView *msg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Would You Like to Keep Clients Synced With iCloud" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        msg.tag = 101;
        [msg show];

    }
    [self registerForiCloudNotifications];
    UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    ClientListViewController *iC = (ClientListViewController *)[nc viewControllers][0];
    iC.context = [self managedObjectContext];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Benjii" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }



    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self storeURL] options:[self storeOptions] error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
-(NSURL *)storeURL{
    return [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Benjii.sqlite"];
}
- (void)registerForiCloudNotifications{
    NSLog(@"Registering");
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(storesWillChange:)
                               name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
                             object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(storesDidChange:)
                               name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification
                             object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:)
                               name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                             object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
}

#pragma mark - iCloud Support
//Use these options in your call to addPersistentStore:
-(NSDictionary *)storeOptions{
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
    [options setObject:@"GraniteCloudStore" forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
    return options;
}

- (void) persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:(NSNotification *)changeNotification{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    [context performBlock:^{
        [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:changeNotification];
    }];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Reload" object:nil];
}

- (void) storesWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error;
        if([context hasChanges]){
            BOOL success = [context save:&error];
            if(!success && error){
                //perform error handling
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
        [context reset];
    }];
    //Refresh User Interface
    NSLog(@"Stores will change");
}

-(void)storesDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    //Refresh your User Interface
    NSLog(@"Stores did change");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Reload" object:nil];
}

-(void)migrateiCloudStoreToLocalStore{
    //assuming you only have one store.
    NSPersistentStore *store = [[_persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] firstObject];
    NSMutableDictionary *localStoreOptions = [[self storeOptions] mutableCopy];
    [localStoreOptions setObject:@YES forKey:NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption];
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:store
                                                                                toURL:[self storeURL]
                                                                              options:localStoreOptions
                                                                             withType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                                error:nil];
    [self reloadStore:newStore];
}

-(void)reloadStore:(NSPersistentStore *)store {
    if(store){
        [_persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:nil];
    }
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:[self storeURL]
                                                    options:[self storeOptions]
                                                      error:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

#pragma mark - Alert View Delegate

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(alertView.tag == 101){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];
        if(buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex){
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"iCloudSupport"];
        }
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
@end
```

and fetchresultcontroller:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)clientResultsController{
    if(clientResultsController != nil){
        return clientResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Client"];
    // NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name beginswith %@"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"finitial" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    //[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                                 managedObjectContext:context
                                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:@"finitial"
                                                                                                            cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.clientResultsController = theFetchedResultController;
    self.clientResultsController.delegate = self;
    return clientResultsController;
}
```

and observer in view Controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"Reload"
                                                      object:self
                                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
                                                      NSLog(@"Reloading");
                                                      [self reloadFetchedResults:note];
                                                  }];

}
```

Sorry if the answer is really simple i checked the other similar questions and they were either unanswered or Outdated (though I tried a couple of them anyway). Any help will be much appreciated
*edit* 
it seems like my observer isnt catching the observerForName:@"Reload"

does anyone know how to add an observer to the method that sends this message:

PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~843477F1-43D0-4E72-BD91-26C3276A9212:GraniteCloudStore
Using local storage: 0

also noticed that if I wait until the above message then rotate the screen also causes table to populate however the persistentStoreCoordinatorDidChange is called before that notice

Comment: I see you've accepted the answer, but did that fix they issue? It would be good to know if it because it enhances my understanding as well

Comment: yes it did work I was using viewDidAppear rather then reloadData. however I am looking into using the fetchedController delegate more. rather then reload table. Ill post what I figure out when I do figure it out

Comment: Thanks dude - that would be great to see. Btw.. in your app, from an old non-icloud version to the version you're working on, does the data show up after the first launch and migrated to the cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue here, but in my case, when I migrate my app from a non-icloud version to an iCloud version, the existing data does not show. Though if I add a new entry, then everything shows and with a debugging, I realised why everything is showing.

In my UITableView, I did the following:

```
- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    if (note)
    {
        [self.timelineTableView reloadData]; 
    }
}
```

In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:) name:@"RefetchAllDatabaseData" object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];
// In your case, the name would be Reload
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Try this - I'm a complete noob here but this worked for me to be able to see changes straight away.

Comment: this works good enough for me although the connection time is still less then optimal. Id like to prevent user input entirely until first connection or failed connection but Ive had time in debugging that the device can take up to 5 minutes and I cant prevent my users from using the app for that long

Comment: That's true - that is a while to wait. I'm trying to figure out similar issues so it would be good to see what solves it

Comment: If this is still an issue, on iOS 8, I know iCloud Drive makes this process about 20x faster.